# What's elegant way to rewrite following LINQ statement using extension methods?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following LINQ statement and I want to rewrite it using extension methods.

```
from x in e
from y in e
from z in e
select new { x, z }
```

One possible solution is:

```
e.Join(e, x => 42, y => 42, (x, y) => new { x, y })
  Join(e, _ => 42, z => 42, (_, z) => new { _.x, z });
```

However this is everything but elegant.

Do you any idea how to improve beauty of second expression?

Comment: Do you really use the same sequence in all three `from` clauses?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes that's the intent. This particular example comes from Eric Mayers channel9 video lecture about functional programming. http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/Functional+Programming/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
e.SelectMany(x => e.SelectMany(y => e.Select(z => new { x, z })))
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `Join` is the wrong approach IMO.

The direct equivalent of this is (I think!):

```
e.SelectMany(x => e.SelectMany(y => e.Select(new { y, z }),
             (x, yz) => new { x, yz.z }))
```

Although I *think* it would be equivalent to:

```
e.SelectMany(x => e.SelectMany(y => e.Select(new { x, z })))
```

Comment: In the sense of beauty `Join` is clearly wrong approach. In the sense of correctness relational algebra (SQL) intuition tells me that this should be fine.

Comment: @Jakub: It might work, but that doesn't make it the right approach. The LINQ equivalent of a cross-join (i.e. where there are no "keys" as such) isn't `Join`, it's `SelectMany`) - even though `SelectMany` itself provides more functionality than this.

Comment: Are these each missing a parethesis?

Comment: Sorry for the nitpick; my brain was having a hard time parsing the first expression without knowing which SelectMany owns the last argument. But it's got an `x` in it, so it should have been obvious.